# Finding duplicates sets of records sharing the same Many-To-Many relations

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pandas, many-to-many

I use Pandas for pre-processing of CSV dataset and convert it to a SQLite database.

I have a many-to-many relation between two entities `A` and `B`, represented by a junction DataFrame `A2B.columns == ['AId', 'BId']`. The uniqueness constraint on `A`s is that each `A` have a different relation to `B`s.

I want to efficiently remove duplicates `A`s based on this constraint. I do it with Pandas like this :

```
AId_dedup = A2B.groupby('AId').BId.apply(tuple).drop_duplicates().index
```

The conversion to tuples allow the comparison of `BIds` collections related to each `AId`.

The relation `A2B` can be seen as a (sparse boolean) matrix, with 1s where a link exists between `A` and `B`. I want to remove duplicated rows of this matrix, alas `pd.unstack()` can't generate sparse matrices. (Also it require efficient hashing of rows)

My questions are :

- What am I trying to do ? In terms of relational algebra ?
- Can it be done more efficiently with Pandas or SQL and (preferably with the SQLite) engine ?

I want to use this operation to find synonyms (duplicate objects) in biological networks where the interactions are represented as tables.

**Edit :** Here is an example of what I want:

```
+-----+-----+
| Aid | Bid |
+-----+-----+
|   1 |   1 |
|   1 |   2 |
|   1 |   3 |
|   2 |   1 |
|   2 |   2 |
|   2 |   3 |
|   3 |   1 |
|   3 |   2 |
|   3 |   3 |
|   3 |   4 |
+-----+-----+

A2B = A2B.groupby('AId').BId.apply(tuple)
+-----+-----------+
| Aid |    Bid    |
+-----+-----------+
|   1 | (1,2,3)   |
|   2 | (1,2,3)   |
|   3 | (1,2,3,4) |
+-----+-----------+

A2B = A2B.drop_duplicates()
+-----+-----------+
| Aid |    Bid    |
+-----+-----------+
|   1 | (1,2,3)   |
|   3 | (1,2,3,4) |
+-----+-----------+
```

Back to junction table (not that easy in Pandas):

```
+-----+-----+
| Aid | Bid |
+-----+-----+
|   1 |   1 |
|   1 |   2 |
|   1 |   3 |
|   3 |   1 |
|   3 |   2 |
|   3 |   3 |
|   3 |   4 |
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Please post sample od your `A` and `B` tables/frames (5-10 rows for each) - this will help us to understand what is the problem

Comment: I put examples of `A2B` entries. `A` and `B` are tables with a PKey in range 1-3 and 1-4 respectively.

Comment: you should change topic to something like: Finding duplicates sets of records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can recreate your A2B table then: create new with unique constrain on ('AId', 'BId'), and then insert data like this:

```
insert into new_A2B select distinct AId, BId from A2B;
```

then do new inserts by sqlite with ON CONFLICT clause like this:

```
insert or ignore into new_A2B values (aid, bid);
```

if you can't  recreate your A2B table, then use distinct when you select rows from it.
Edit:
You can find duplicates id by this query:

```
select A2B.aid, dup.aid
from A2B
left join A2B as dup on dup.bid = A2B.bid
group by A2B.aid, dup.aid
having count(A2B.bid) = count(dup.bid)
and count(A2B.bid) = (select count(bid) from A2B where aid = dup.aid)
```

if you need, you can add where condition to find duplicates only for lower id like this

```
where A2B.aid < dup.aid
```

Maybe this query will be faster:

```
with
  c as (select aid, count(1) as c
    from A2B
    group by aid) 
select A2B.aid, dup.aid
from A2B
inner join c as ac on ac.aid = A2B.aid
left join A2B as dup on dup.bid = A2B.bid and A2B.aid < dup.aid 
and exists(select 1 from c where aid = dup.aid and c = ac.c)
group by A2B.aid, dup.aid
having count(A2B.bid) = count(dup.bid)
and count(A2B.bid) = (select count(bid) from A2B where aid = dup.aid)
```

Edit: 
There is one more solution that you can test (it is possible, that this is fastest query):

```
with
  c as (select aid, min(bid) as f, max(bid) as l, count(1) as c
    --, sum(bid) as s
    from A2B
    group by aid) 
select f.aid, dup.aid
from c as f inner join c as dup 
on f.aid < dup.aid and f.f = dup.f and f.l - dup.l and f.c = dup.c 
--and f.s = dup.s
Where f.c = (
  select count(1) 
  where A2B as t1 
  inner join A2B as t2
  on t1.aid < t2.aid and t1.bid = t2.bid and t1.aid = f.aid and t2.aid = dup.aid)
```

you can also try uncomment sum(bid) as s & and f.s = dup.s

Comment: The junction table doesn't contains duplicates. It's the `A`s that are duplicated relatively to their relation with `B`s. I just added an example to my post.

Comment: Thanks ! Wow It's quite complex. Your response is fine, I will benchmark it against my Pandas one liner. I was hopping a more simple solution, though. It's for a class project, so I try to keep things simple.
I keep the question open for another day.

Comment: try next query, I'm think that is more simple and faster

Comment: Can you write with query is fastest?